# Android Asus seven inch hdpi tablet layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

Am developing an app with multiple screen support. Before start developing i read developer site for multiple screen support. Currently i had an issue regarding device density. I tested my application in Samsung Tab 10inch, Toshiba Regza, Customized 10inch tab,Samsung tab3, Lenova tabs. The deviece mentioned here all are mdpi devices. So i used layout-sw-720 for 10 inch tablets and layout-sw-600 for 7 inch tablets. When i tried to run on ASUS MeMO Pad HD 7inch  whcih is an high density device it didn't takes layout from none of my layout folders specified. ASUS MeMO Pad HD 7'c confoguration is 7" LED Backlight WXGA (1280x800) Screen. Please help me with exact folder structure by considering the device density also. It's been a head ache for me since one week. Please help me. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by giving prefix hdpi to the folder layout-sw600dp like layout-sw600dp-hdpi. Actually my layouts contains kind of complicated designs and images,so if i didn't specify the layout folder name like i mentioned above, then it will take layout from the layout-sw600dp with no density prefix. Then to avoid that i used hdpi prefix to the layout folder and same to the drawable folder.